# How to open files in react received from API call

Tags: reactjs, filereader

An API call returns files that can be text or pdf file or doc. What is the best way to present these documents to the user? Is there any npm module that can work with many file formats (`.pdf`, `.text`, `.doc`)? Thanks in advance

Comment: i recommend you start from this one https://github.com/plangrid/react-file-viewer

Comment: this does not work it crashes my app

Comment: Which type of files you have docx/xslx or doc/xsl? It's important because of react-file-viewer supported next file formats: png, jpeg, gif, bmp, including 360-degree images, pdf, csv, xslx, docx, mp4, webm, mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the api you mentioned gives you files in the form of a downloadable link, then you can use Google Docs's Embedded viewer
Use it as follows

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=[path_to_file]embedded=truestyle="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"/>`

Replace `path_to_file` with the link you get from the api. It supports the file formats you mentioned in the question